# Clip linestring layer by polygons (partly overlapping)

Tags: qgis, postgis, gdal, r

I have a linestring layer that I want to clip with a polygon layer. So far so good. However, as these polygons are river catchments starting from a sampling site, they are sometimes overlapping (due to multiple sampling sites on a river). When this is the case, I want the clipped linestring to be duplicated according to the number of overlapping polygons (i.e. I want to have a linestring for each polygon within each polygon).

To illustrate you my example I've uploaded two sample shapes [here](https://owncloud.uni-koblenz-landau.de/owncloud/s/5syI7hwBw1uXMxj). It contains 3 overlapping polygons and a linestring. My actual data consists of ~ 2500 polygons and a stream network for whole Germany.

[image]

One possibility that comes to my mind would be to loop through all the polygons' unique ID and clip them individually with the line network. However I ask myself, if there are already functions in QGIS, PostGIS, or R that can do this?

using the loop strategy in R I came with the code below.
It's basically working, but I still have problems when a line has multiple segments within a polygon and it's extremely slow compared to the clip function in QGIS for example.

```
require(sf)
ezg_fin = st_read('polygons.shp')
gew_typ = st_read('line.shp')

todo = ezg_fin$site_id

line_list = list()
for (i in 1:length(todo)) {
  catchm = ezg_fin[ezg_fin$site_id == todo[i], ]
  line_sub = gew_typ[catchm, ] # 1st spatial subset the stream segment (fast!) - only possible 'cause stream network is segmented
  message(i, '. ', 'Clipping river at: ', todo[i])
  line_clip = st_intersection(line_sub, catchm) # 2nd clip only the subsetted segement (whole stream network would take way too long!)

  line_list[[i]] = line_clip
}

fin = do.call(rbind, line_list)
```

Comment: Did you already try anything? I would say postgis is very suitable for the job but it helps if you already have some code or workflow that we can comment on.

Comment: I'm currently trying it in R using a spatial subset `[`, as the actual line network is not unified (i.e. segments roughly the size of the bigger polygons). However this doesn't really clip the line at the border. I also tried `sf::st_intersection()` which is pretty slow 'cause my actual line network is really big. I elaborate a bit more and will provide some code then. My general strategy is looping through the polygon IDs.

Comment: You could use the sp classes, imported using rgdal::readOGR, and the sp::over function or intersect functions in rgeos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a great wrapper function in the raster package, using rgeos::gIntersects, that will return exactly what you are after.

```
library(sp)
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

l <- rgdal::readOGR(getwd(), "line")
p <- rgdal::readOGR(getwd(), "polygons") 
sp::proj4string(p) <- sp::proj4string(l)

lp <- raster::intersect(l,p)
str(lp@data) 
  plot(p)
  plot(lp, col="red", add=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2):

QGIS example using **Clip**.

[image]

1. Make sure your layers are on the same CRS. (I have reprojected polygons layer to EPSG:31467, same as line layer).
2. `Processing Toolbox | QGIS geoalgorithms | Vector overlay tools | Clip`
3. Select Input `line` and Clip `polygons`
4. Click on `Iterate over this layer` button of the `Clip layer`
5. Probably the output needs to be set to file ([Create temporary layer] may not work). Hit [Run]

One clipped line layer per polygon (total three) will be generated.